# JdbcTemplate not updating

Tags: jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I am trying to issue a simple `batchUpdate` via JdbcTemplate on **ORACLE** database. I keep getting update return values as `-2`. I can complete the update via simple jdbc `preparedStatement`. But `JdbcTemplate` isn't able to do the same. What does the return value `-2` from JdbcTemplate means anyway?

Comment: Could you paste some code? Difficult to diagnose without. -2 is returned by Oracle, not by the JdbcTemplate.

Comment: As @sorencito mentioned add your code, also check the logs what exact query is being sent to DB.

Comment: I will give the code shortly. I am unable to obtain exact query sent by `OJDBC`. Oracle's JDBC driver's `PreparedStatement` doesn't give query on `toString()`

Comment: Oops, seems it was really a database issue. The lines to be updated weren't committed. I am able to update now, but still getting `-2` as return value. I have come to know that `-2` means that the driver wasn't able to obtain the count of number of lines affected.